# Common annotations used in different test classes

Tags: java, annotations, testng, testng-annotation-test

I have a question regarding annotations like `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeMethod`. Is it possible to set a global annotations, so that all my test classes will be use them? I have in my framework over 20 test classes with a lot of test methods. Every test class has preconditions like `@BeforeTest` or `@BeforeMethod`, but for each test class this preconditions are the same. So I think this might be a good idea, to write a common annotations methods, which could be used in every test class.

Comment: Use a listener.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How can use it? Can you explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the code reusable using inheritance. Create a super class `DefaultTestCase`:

```
public class DefaultTestCase{
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
     System.out.println("beforeTest");
  }  
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("beforeMethod");
  }  
}
```

and each test case class extends the `DefaultTestCase`:

```
public class ATest extends DefaultTestCase{
  @Test
  public void test() {
     System.out.println("test");
  }
  @Test
  public void anotherTest() {
     System.out.println("anotherTest");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
beforeTest
beforeMethod
test
beforeMethod
anotherTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an implementation of `ITestListener` and `IClassListener`, you could do as below. `onTestStart` would be invoked before each test case and `onStart` would be invoked for `<test>` in your suite and `onBeforeClass` is executed once for each class.

```java
public class MyListener implements ITestListener, IClassListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // Put the code in before test.
        beforeTestLogic();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeforeClass(ITestClass testClass) {
        // Put the code in before class.
        beforeClassLogic();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // Put the code in before method.
        beforeMethodLogic();
    }
}
```

Now add the `@Listener` annotation to the required test classes:

```java
@Test
@Listener(MyListener.class)
public class MyTest {
    // ........
}
```